# Shopware 6: Unable to parse file services.xml on XAMPP

Tags: php, xml, xampp, shopware, shopware6

I'm running Shopware 6.4 locally using XAMPP 8.0.28 server (MacOs).

After installing Shopware and linking the virtual host, I get this error message:

> Unable to parse file "<PATH_TO_FILE>/services.xml": The XML file "<PATH_TO_FILE>/services.xml"
> is not valid.

[image: Exception screenshot]

I think it is missing permission/credentials. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but unless you have touched that file there's something weird going on with your development environment, as this vendor file is definitely valid. `Xampp` has proven time and time again to be difficult to use with modern platforms, as it's either missing extensions or being configured weirdly. You should invest the time to set up a proper development environment.

There are multiple options that are better suited:

- [`homebrew`](https://medium.com/@JanFaessler/setup-local-lamp-stack-on-mac-with-homebrew-47eb8d6d53ea) (not specific to Shopware)
- [`dockware`](https://dockware.io/)
- [`shopware-docker`](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker)
- [`devenv`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/devenv) (recommended to look into that option)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found the answer to my Xampp issue and posted it .. but I appreciate your effort and knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the mentioned issue after a long time.

By default XAMPP doesn't inherit the user access permissions, so you need to adjust it in the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`

Find the part for the `User` and `Group`:

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon
```

And change the 'daemon' values to your current user/group names.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was cache-clearing

command: `bin/console cache:clear`

Next, reload the web page